# MySQL equivalent to Pandas to_datetime function

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have an unsigned int that I convert to datetime using:

```
pd.to_datetime(date_and_time,unit="s",origin='1906-05-01')
```

How can i convert this using MySQL? I tried `from_unixtime(date_and_time)`, but it just returns NULL

Comment: What's your int value?

Comment: 2626070399, i.e. '1989-07-18 07:59:59'

Comment: `select from_unixtime(floor(2626070399/1000))` gives '1970-01-31 09:27:50'

Comment: See https://www.epochconverter.com/. It doesn't seem like your EPOCH is actually the datetime you think it is.

Comment: Nope, this question is not a duplicate of the unix timestamp conversion question, since this is not a unix timestamp. The epoch is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard unix timestamp, since you set the starting point to `'1906-05-01'`. Basically, what you need is `'1906-05-01' + 2626070399 seconds`.

You can achieve this with the following mysql query:

```
select date_add('1906-05-01',interval 2626070399 second)
```

Or

```
select '1906-05-01' + interval 2626070399 second
```